# Getting statistical values from deeply nested dictionary with k8s resource recommendations in YAML string

Tags: python, pandas

Since [Goldilocks](https://github.com/FairwindsOps/goldilocks) only supports machine-readable output via the CLI, which is namespace-scoped, I wrote a script to scrape every pod in every namespace in every cluster using requests, [kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), and beautifulsoup. It basically grabs the YAML code blocks out of the DOM, which look like this:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 812m
    memory: 4506M
  limits:
    cpu: 1151m
    memory: 4999M
```

I then dump those into a [nested_dict](https://pypi.org/project/nested_dict/), which looks like this:

```
"cluster": {
    "namespace": {
        "soa": "resources:
                 requests:
                   cpu: 812m
                   memory: 4506M
                 limits:
                   cpu: 1151m
                   memory: 4999M"
        }
    }
}
```

From there, I parse values out into another nested_dict:

```
soa_recs = nested_dict()
# First, flatten out a given cluster's items
for k, v in orig_dict[cluster_name].items_flat():
    for soa in k:
        # Example line for a given SOA:
        # ['resources:', '  requests:', '    cpu: 812m', '    memory: 4506M', '  limits:', '    cpu: 1151m', '    memory: 4999M']
        line = v.split("\n")
        # Strip out whitespace and split values out
        request_cpu = line[2].strip().split(":")[1]
        request_mem = line[3].strip().split(":")[1]
        limit_cpu = line[5].strip().split(":")[1]
        limit_mem = line[6].strip().split(":")[1]
        # Fill new nested_dict with values
        soa_recs[k[0]][k[1]]["requests"]["cpu"] = request_cpu
        soa_recs[k[0]][k[1]]["requests"]["memory"]  = request_mem
        soa_recs[k[0]][k[1]]["limits"]["cpu"] = limit_cpu
        soa_recs[k[0]][k[1]]["limits"]["memory"] = limit_mem
```

I now need to generate statistical values for a given SOA's CPU and Memory requests/limits - min/max/median/average is probably sufficient. Preferably, I'd have these values for a given cluster, as well as across n clusters. The units aren't guaranteed, but can be split out and compared to do the math - for instance, memory could be presented in M[B] or G[B].

I could just go further with the nested_dict, and probably do some dict comprehension and the statistics library, but I feel like Pandas is probably a better solution. Dumping the nested_dict straight into Pandas works, and gives me this:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

Pandas is smart enough to let me split out the row values based on their keys, so I presume I could do something with iloc and mean, but I'm not sure how. Potentially adding a twist, not all SOAs are deployed to all namespaces, and of course this is only one cluster, although it's not a deal-breaker to have multiple dataframes, one for each cluster.

Open to any suggestions if there's a neater way to accomplish this; I'm not married to Pandas.

Comment: you can use `df.stack().apply(pd.Series)` to filter the NA values, then left `requests` and `limits` as the columns name. And the level_0 index is the raw index, level_1 index the the raw column names.

Comment: That works to make it a multi-index; still struggling to generate values. I can do something like this:
    df["limits"]["api-ingest"].apply(lambda x: x["memory"]).mean() for a single value, but it'd be nice to apply it across everything at once.

Comment: Got some progress with applymap():
df.applymap(lambda x: x["memory"])["limits"].max() for example. Just have to figure out how to get the key as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up fixing this by splitting the problem up, rather than trying to do operations on the entire dataframe.

```
# First, make a nested_dict so we don't have to deal with
# manually creating the levels.
mega_dict = nested_dict()

# Next, get clusters and namespaces, then loop through those.
for cluster_name, namespace_list in cluster_namespaces.items():
    print(f"Getting data from {cluster_name}")
    # For each namespace in a given cluster, parse the HTML.
    for namespace in namespace_list:
        html = get_html(cluster_name, domain, namespace)
        soup_dict = make_soup(html)
        # For a given SOA and its recommendations, populate our nested_dict.
        for soa, recs in soup_dict.items():
            mega_dict[cluster_name][namespace][soa] = recs


...

# For each cluster, loop through a flattened structure of the
# recommendation nested_dict. If it's a memory entry, convert the
# bytes (previously converted from whatever format it was in
# for consistent math) back into human readable format, then enter it.
# If it's a CPU entry, just append it. If it's anything else,
# something went wrong, so raise SystemExit and print an error.

cpu_values = []
memory_values = []
cpu_columns = ["namespace", "soa", "millicores"]
memory_columns = ["namespace", "soa", "size"]

for cluster in cluster_list:
    for k, v in recs[cluster][limit_or_rec].items_flat():
        if "memory" in k:
            memory_values.append((k[0], k[1], convert_bytes_to_human_readable(v, mib)))
        elif "cpu" in k:
            cpu_values.append((k[0], k[1], int(v)))
        else:
            print("Error finding recommendations - can you connect to the cluster?")
            raise SystemExit

...

# Create dataframes from our two lists.
cpu_df = pd.DataFrame(cpu_values, columns=cpu_columns, dtype=float)
memory_df = pd.DataFrame(
    memory_values, columns=memory_columns, dtype=float)

...

# Create another nested_dict, and create the entries from the dataframe
# with limits or requests as an arg, and appending either
# Mi/Gi for memory, or m (millicores) for CPU.
soa_dict = nested_dict()
soa_dict["resources"]["limits"]["cpu"] = f"{cpu_lim_df[('millicores'), lim_stat][soa]}m"
soa_dict["resources"]["limits"]["memory"] = f"{mem_lim_df[('size', lim_stat)][soa]}{unit}"
soa_dict["resources"]["requests"]["cpu"] = f"{cpu_req_df[('millicores', req_stat)][soa]}m"
soa_dict["resources"]["requests"]["memory"] = f"{mem_req_df[('size', req_stat)][soa]}{unit}"
```

Not sure if that captures everything; [the source code is here.](https://github.com/stephanGarland/goldilocks-scraper)